# Как подтвердить действие ?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как подтвердить действие и нажать эту кнопку `OK` с помощью `selenium` ?

- Это `alret javascript-а`
- Впервые столкнулся при автоматизации с подобным модальным окном(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть класс Alert, думаю, должен вам помочь.

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Или с ожиданием

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ec.alert_is_present).accept()
```